# Are there really differences in transport phenomena?

Tags: energy

Is not the division into momentim, mass and heat transfer obsolete? Heat transfer through conduction is transferred through collisons on the boundary and thereby transfer momentum. Convection is not only heat transferred but also mass. 
Which sense does the differentiaon have?

Answer (score 0):

In the chemical engineering world, the noted descriptors define distinctly different phenomena.  Momentum transfer refers to fluid flow, mass transfer refers to diffusion and associated phenomena, and heat transfer refers to energy transfer.  For purposes of remaining clearly understood, and due to the historical development of these fields of study, there is no way that the chemical engineering community would agree to combining all of these descriptors into one descriptor.